# First or create method , creating duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i'm trying to use the find or create method to update a skill if it already exists or create it if it doesn't. I can create a new skill fine but when i try update a skill that already exists it does update the skill but also creates a duplicate skill with the same data.

```
def create
  @project = Project.find params[:project_id]
  @skills_required = @project.skills_requireds.new(skills_required_params)
  skills = SkillsRequired.where(skills_required_params.slice(:skill_id)).first_or_create
  skills.update(skills_required_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @skills_required.save    
      format.html{ redirect_to @project, notice: "Skills required added for #{@project.projectName}" }
    else
      format.html{ redirect_to @project, notice: "Something went wrong, unable to update required skills " }
    end
  end
end
```

Form:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="top-border left"></div>
  <div class="top-border right"></div>
  <h3> Skill Required</h3>
  <%= form_for([@project, SkillsRequired.new]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :skill_id %><br>
      <%= f.collection_select :skill_id, Skill.all, :id, :skillType, :prompt => "Select Skill" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :numWorkers %><br>
      <%= f.number_field :numWorkers %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :skillLevel %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :skillLevel %>
    </div>
    <%=f.submit "Add Skill" %>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

I've tried adding a skills_required destroy to my controller but this doesn't allow me to add a new skill. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: i'm guessing the root of your problem is these variables, both of which you're saving: `@skills_required` and `skills`.

Comment: So is it possible to call this method in the create method?  Is their a method I can call to check if a skill exists before it is saved?

Comment: You are calling `.new(...).save` on one variable, and `first_or_create` on another. So of course it's going to create two records :)

Comment: Don't know how I didn't realize that, got it working thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching the problem wrong. You need a model level validation which enforces what `skill requirements` are valid:

```
# Your model names should be nouns - not adjectives
class SkillRequirement < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :skill_id, scope: :project_id'
end
```

If you want users to be able to specify the same skill but at different levels you can do it like so:

```
# Your model names should be nouns - not adjectives
class SkillRequirement < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :skill_id, scope: [:project_id, :level] 
end
```

You should also combine this with a database index to avoid race conditions.

```
add_index(:skill_requirements, [:project_id, :skill_id], unique: true, name: 'by_skill_and_project')
```

Since updating existing skill requirements should be handled by a seperate update action you don't need all that bloat in your controller:

```
class SkillRequirementsController
  before_action :set_project

  def create
    @skill_requirement = @project.skill_requirements.new(skill_requirement_params)
    if @skill_requirement.save
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @skill_requirement = @project.skill_requirements.find(params[:id])
    if @skill_requirement.update(skill_requirement_params)
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private 

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

  def skill_requirement_params
    params.require(:skill_requirement).permit(:)
  end
end
```